# Graphical issue not displaying the main character

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added the main player charachter but in Android version its not visible there is a kind of moving shadow something like that instead of character, I deleted the character animations and materials nothing worked, but in PC version and and inside Unity it is visible without any problem`[enter code here][1]`

Comment: Hello! There's a lot of details missing from this question.  Can you add a screenshot of the inspector while the character is select?  And perhaps screenshots of what it looks like playing in Unity vs playing on Android?

Comment: I tried to add a screenshot from both devices but  i couldnt add it in question cuz I am new in here and I need get more scores 

Comment: is there anyway that I can send you the screenshots. Thanks

Comment: You might be able to upload it to imgur and then comment with the link. I forget what you are and aren't able to post with a new account; sorry.

Comment: http://imgur.com/CB6dpSW

Comment: That black disform object is the main character that looks like that in Android version